# <!-- summary --> comments don’t produce user cards anymore

Tags: support, user-card

If I add a `<!-- summary: custom card content -->` block to my “About Me”, it seems to disable my user card entirely.

Alternatively, [support](/questions/tagged/support): was this feature removed? I can’t find any mention of that happening.

Comment: Well your example won't work... there needs to be a minimum of 28 characters... or does that answer your question?

Comment: @Cai: It might! However, I know my previous summary `<!-- summary: I â™¥ UTF-8. -->` worked for years.

Comment: @Cai: Yep, works as expected with enough characters. Post an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a minimum of 28 character required for the user card to show. This has always been the case (as noted by @animuson in comments) so if this was previously working it was possibly a bug.

From [Help Center > Privileges > Established User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user):

> If you don't want the exact text of your About Me section there (such as it is too long and gets cut off, or because the formatting is weird), then you may use a summary comment using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> <!-- summary: [your text here] -->
> ```
>
> Replace [your text here] with your desired summary (**of at least 28 characters**), and that will be placed on your expanded usercard in place of your About Me section.

So...

```
<!-- summary: custom card content -->
```

won't work.

```
<!-- summary: Lorem scelerisque sagittis? Placerat elit velit eros purus pellentesque lacus cursus? Ut elementum sit porta? -->
```

on the other hand, works fine.

Comment: There has always been a minimum length requirement. It even appears in revision 1 of the [original announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/104810/revisions).

Comment: @animuson any idea if the limit has changed? (That post says there *is* a limit but not *what* that limit is...) or any idea how OP previously [had a shorter summary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290823/summary-comments-don-t-produce-user-cards-anymore#comment944245_290823)?

Comment: Possibly a bug that was causing it not to be applied? The help center article you linked hasn't been edited since it was created in 2013, so it's been the same for a long time.

Comment: Note: As of 2020, [expanded usercards were made available to everyone, and the character requirement was lowered from 28 to 6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342575/335251).