# Profile preview does not work for all posts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-card, posts

If you know, there is something like popover in all posts' authors area. So when I hover the author's avatar, I get some information about him. So, this does not work for all posts.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking at is actually called the "expanded user card."

When a user fills out the *About Me* section of their profile, and the text within it is [at least 6 characters long,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342575/622284) the user card will expand.

The user you hovered over first in your .gif demonstration, [Mad Scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151385/mad-scientist), has a blank about me at the moment (this text field becomes "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them." when a user hasn't filled out their about me section.) As a result, their user card will not expand.

Test it yourself! Head on over to [your profile's edit page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), clear out your *About Me* section, save your changes, and then come back to this page. Then, hover over your avatar, and you'll notice that the card will not expand.

Answer (score 5):

That user does not have a profile description and thus, per the current rules, is not eligible for the preview when hovering their profile picture.

We plan to eventually redo those popups and enable them for all users, regardless of whether they have a bio, but there is currently no timeline for when that will happen.

In the meantime, this is working as designed.

Comment: understandable. I guess the card for users who don't have bio section, will have the same "Apparently, this user prefers to keep...", am I right?