# Disable links on expanded user card for users with less than 15 rep

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, spam, user-card

Links on "About me" and "Website link" are disabled for users with less than 15 rep due to potential spammers (ref: [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105228/241919)). However, *links on expanded user card are still enabled even for users with 1 rep.*

> **User profile (no hyperlinks)**
>
> [image]
>
> **Expanded user card (full with hyperlinks)**
>
> [image]

---

For the live demo, [Arulkumar has provided a practical comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334941/can-we-make-the-expanded-user-card-privilege-universal#comment1147004_342575),

> I little worried about the privilege to the [spam accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=insurance) <sup>(link to the list of users page with "insurance" keyword prefilled)</sup>

(or try [the list of recent users getting Autobiographer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer))

---

Even though Yaakov, a Stack Exchange staff has [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334941/can-we-make-the-expanded-user-card-privilege-universal#comment1147005_342575) that

> [...] As far as spam accounts, we are not worried about the impact here.

Please reconsider disabling them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This request is complete. All the users who have links disabled in profile page, now also have links disabled in their user profile popup. Thanks for reporting this issue!