# The expanded user card is not being displayed to me. What I'm missing? As of August 2023, are there system or privileges requirements?

Tags: support, user-card

The expanded user card is not showing when I mouse hover on any question and answer user card. I have looked at top users and staff I know that have set information in the About section of their user profile. I.E. the expanded user card is not shown for any post creator in [Design Vision Updates to the User Card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392107/1395520).

What am I missing? Is there a system, account, privilege or any other requirement?

---

#### Literature Review

##### Help Center

From [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/expanded-user-card)

> When anyone is viewing your user card below a question or answer, or on the Users page, they may hover over your profile image to produce an expanded user card that contains extra information. This is also known as a hover card.

The referred article doesn't mention system or privilege requirements.

#### Meta Stack Exchange

According to [Yaakov Elis's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342575/1395520) to [Can we make the "expanded user card" privilege universal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334941/1395520), created in 2020, the privileges requirements were removed.

#### User and System

##### This account

- When I'm posting this, it has rep 1.
- The account is in good standing: no post bans, no suspensions.
- The account hasn't associated accounts, i.e., Stack Overflow or other Stack Exchange sites accounts.

##### Anonymous user

- Using Chrome, Firefox and Safari as anonymous users, having accepted all the cookies, the expanded user card is not displayed

##### Alternate accounts

- I have also tested this using my alternate accounts. Some have multiple associated accounts, i.e. Stack Overflow, Super User, etc. My oldest account has +30k rep on two sites. The expanded user account doesn't work either. Tested on multiple sites, including Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

##### System

My system:

- Mac Mini, chip Apple M1
- MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d)
- Browsers:

  - Chrome
  - Firefox
  - Safari

The Console of the Chrome DevTools doesn't show any message.

Comment: Your user card works for me (iOS Chrome, long tap). In fact, I commented about this same thing earlier this week.

Comment: Which part of the card are you hovering? For me it only works on the profile picture.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqI6X.png). Even when logged out, so I really don't think it has anything to do with permissions or reputation or account status.

Comment: Just by any chance, are you hovering over the avatar specifically? If you hover over any other thing in the card than the avatar, it won't appear.

Comment: I think Laurel was talking about [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392107/design-vision-updates-to-the-user-card/392121#comment1311636_392121), not the one you highlighted from a completely different user.

Comment: A) Are you hovering over the user's profile picture/Gravatar? B) Are you hovering over the picture/Gravatar on a user's usercard for which there is an expanded version? Not all user' have an expanded usercard available. There isn't one for users who don't have an "about me" and/or who have explicitly disabled an expanded usercard from being shown for them by using the method described in the Help Center page you've linked: [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/expanded-user-card) For testing, you should be able to use your own usercard on this question.

Comment: You've had a lot of feedback here, but no response so far. Is the disconnect really just that `when I ... hover on any ... user card` != `they may hover over your profile image`? e.g. you were expecting the user card to expand when you hover _anywhere_ on the card, vs. what is documented which is only over the _image_?

Comment: Was the browser javascript enabled?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. My mistake was that while I passed the mouse pointer over the user profile image on the post user card, I didn't keep it quiet enough to allow the expanded user card to be displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake. I was passing the mouse pointer around the user card instead of keeping it quiet enough over the user profile image.

[image: Mouse hovering over user profile image]

H/T

> Which part of the card are you hovering? For me it only works on the profile picture. –
> [bobble x time units ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392214/the-expanded-user-card-is-not-being-displayed-to-me-what-im-missing-as-of-aug#comment1311922_392214)

Comment: I left this answer as a draft during the weekend due to a technical problem unrelated to the expanded user card.